# Pulling lines n to m from list of files found

Tags: text-processing, tail, head

Ultimately I need to grab lines 3-53 from each CSV in each subdirectory.

I grabbed the lines from one file like so ('cat' isn't necessarily required):

```
cat /[path]/[file].csv | head -53 | tail -51
```

and the files I need like this ('find' *is* required):

```
find /[path]/ -name "*.csv"
```

The problem is I'm having trouble linking the two together. Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: OK, look in the direction of `xargs`. You might also want to look at `sed -n '3,53p'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /path/to/file/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.csv' -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do sed -n '3,53p' $file; done
```

Notice `print0` option which take care of any possible whitespace characters in the file names.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should help you, if I understand you correctly.

Script/line:

```
$ for csv_files in $(find /home/t1/ -name "*.csv"); do echo $csv_files ; done
```

Output:

```
/home/t1/t4/t4.csv
/home/t1/t1/t1.csv
/home/t1/t2/t2.csv
/home/t1/t3/t3.csv
```

Instead of the `echo` you can insert your second command `cat $csv_files | head -53 | tail -51`

For a sense of completion, I substituted the `echo` line:

```
$ for csv_files in $(find /home/t1/ -name "*.csv"); do cat $csv_files | head -53 | tail -51; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to accomplish this using find itself

```
find path -type f -name '*.csv' \
-exec sh -c 'for f; do head -n 53 "$f" | tail -n 51; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: That's exactly [the method] I was trying to do it!  I just couldn't get the syntax right.